# I get an error when adding sound in splash

Tags: android, splash-screen

when I add sound in Splash, I get an error
`org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException`

But when removing the sound command, I can run it

```
handler = new Handler();
        splashSound = MediaPlayer.create(SplashActivity.this,
                R.raw.correct1);
        splashSound.start();  //<<<play sound on Splash Screen
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);

        AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
        InputStream is1 = null;

        try {
            is1 = assetManager.open("img/ic_launcher_pepak");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);
        ImageView logomil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logomil);
        logomil.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2500;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //start your Next Activity here
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of error]